# Can't get navigator.notification.activityStart(); to work in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

I'm trying to display the network busy spinner icon on IOS devices when the app is accessing data from other sites, but the program freezes when I use this code in my js file:

```
navigator.notification.activityStart();
//ajax request...
navigator.notification.activityStop();
```

I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 with Phonegap Build 2.0.0. Is there a preference in the config.xml file that needs to be set for this? Or something else??

I found some similar posts, but they refer to a plugin that involves loading what looks like xcode libraries which I don't think can be done as I'm using only html & javascript.

Answer (score -3):

I think for iOS you need to use

```
navigator.notification.loadingStart();
navigator.notification.loadingStop();
```